# django server uses old url.py file with new project

Tags: python, django

I'm in the process of learning django. I started a project called "mysite" following one of the tutorials. Then I started another project. But when I run "python manage.py runserver" in my new project directory, and then try to load an app of the new project, it returned error because the server was still reading "mysite.urls", and couldn't find my newly defined url. Below is the screen shot error message.

And help is appreciated.

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is your newly defined url? Django will always look at the

> mysite/mysite/url.py

I'm guessing you didn't edit this but added some other urls in an app.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what's the reason of the error. I was running two "python manage.py runserver" instances with two opened cmd windows. I closed the one which I ran from "mysite" directory and then I could reach the url for the new project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem my mistake was I was trying to run the new server from the terminal of visual studio code while my old server was still running in CMD.I closed CMD and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

there are several points here you may wanna check:

- if server doesn't start at all, you may have other processes that using the same port(maybe another instance of the application is running)
- if your new app is not shown and you have restarted the server, then check your server settings in the `<your project name>/settings.py` and look for the `INSTALLED_APPS` list and make sure your new app is appended there like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-an-app-in-django/)
- maybe you don't have any route to your new app in the '/urls.py`(this is too close to your question)